# Can I prompt the user with carousels instead of buttons in the Bot Framework?

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

I would like to know if it is possible to have a PromptDialog with carousels instead of buttons.

For example, if I want to prompt the user with choices I can do something like this:

```
public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
{
    IEnumerable<string> options = new List<string>
    {
        "First Option",
        "Second Option",
        "Third Option",
        "Fourth Option"
    };

    PromptDialog.Choice(context, AfterPromptDialogChoice, options, "Choose an option");
}

private async Task AfterPromptDialogChoice(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
{
    string input = await result;
    await context.PostAsync(input);
    context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
}
```

The key here for me is that after the user chooses an option I can handle the choice inside the AfterPromptDialogChoice method. What I would like is to prompt the user with a carousel, and when he chooses one one of the carousel items I would like to redirect the flow to an delegate method where I can perform some operations based on the users choice.

I know that using a regular carousel I can use an CardAction to send back the option the user selected, however this option's value (text) will be send again to the bot and won't be related to the user choice. I just would like to have the behavior of the PromptDialog.Choice, but with a carousel to display the options, instead of only buttons Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You might have to provide your [PromptStyler](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/PromptDialog.cs#L178) to the [PromptOptions](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/PromptDialog.cs#L157) of the PromptChoice.

The PromptStyler is the one responsible of applying the proper PromptStyle to the options.

It's something that you would have to explore and see if it will suits all your needs.